# $ \gcd(x^n-1,x^m-1)=x^d-1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, gcd-and-lcm

Show $$ \gcd(x^n-1,x^m-1)=x^d-1$$

---

Trying Euclidian Algorithm where $n=mq+r$
$$ x^n-1=x^m-1 q(x)+x^{r}-1$$

Now

$$\begin{aligned}
 \gcd(x^n-1,x^m-1)&=gcd(x^n-1,x^r-1)
                   \\&= \vdots
                   \\&= x^d-1
\end{aligned}$$

---

Trying out with basic defitions

**GCD polynomials** $\in F[x]$

$\forall f,h \in F[x]$ ,where ($f\neq 0 \vee g\neq 0$)
$\exists $(unique) $d\in F[x]$

s.t.

1. $d|f\wedge d|h$
2. $d$ is monic
3. $d$ has maximal degree and $d|f\wedge d|h$

---

Def **Euclidean Domain** $gcd$

Let $R$ be a Euclidean domain

$\forall a,b \in R$ where at leats one is not zero
,$\exists d \in R$ s.t

1. $d|a \wedge d |b$
2. $c|a,c|b \Rightarrow \delta(c) \leq \delta (d)$

Guessing $\delta$ is somekind of  norm

**Def gcd Integers**

$\forall a,b \in Z$ both not zero, $\exists d\in Z$ s.t

1. $d|a \wedge d|b$
2. $c|a\wedge c|b \Rightarrow c\leq d$

---

Using **basic tools**

does $d|n$ so $n=k_1 d $ ,$\exists k_1 \in Z$ s.t

$$\begin{aligned}
x^n-1&=(x^d-1)(x^{k_1}+1)=x^{d+k_1}-1
\end{aligned} $$

---

**More tools**

**Thm 1.2 Hungerford**
$\forall a,b \in Z$ (not both 0) \exists u,v\in Z (not necassary unique)$

s.t. $$ d=nu+mv$$

**Thm for polynomials**

$\forall f(x),h(x) \in F[x] , \exists u(x),v(x) \in F[x]$

s.t. $$ d(x)=f(x)u(x)+g(x)v(x)$$

---

Trying an example to see somekind of a pattern and then try to work an argument in genal

considering $x^6-1$ and $x^2-1$

$$ x^6-1=(x^2-1)(x^4+x^2+x)+0$$

the $gcd(6,2)=2$ so the gcd in polynomials is

$ x^6-1=(x^2-1)(x^4+x^2+1)+0$

Comment: Look at the complex roots.

Comment: Do you want the gcd of two polynomials or of two integers of a specific form?

Comment: Didn't you forget to say that $\;d=g.c.d.(n,m)\;$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:
$$x^m-1=\prod_{k=1}^{m}\left(x-e^{\frac{\pi i k}m}\right)$$
$$x^n-1=\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(x-e^{\frac{\pi i k}n}\right)$$
Since all those factors are prime in $\mathbb{C}[X]$ and $\mathbb{C}[X]$ is a UFD, $\gcd(x^m-1,x^n-1)$ is equal to the product of the common factors, aka factors
$$\left(x-e^{\frac{i\pi k}m}\right)$$
for which there is an $1\le l\le n$ with:
$$e^{\frac{\pi i l}n}=e^{\frac{\pi i k}m}\implies \frac ln=\frac km$$
looking at those fractions in their lowest terms, both must have equal denominators and that denominator must divide both $m$ and $n$. So if we let $d=\gcd(n,m)$, then that fraction must be $j/d$ for some $j$. Therefore:
$$\gcd(x^m-1,x^n-1)\mid\prod_{k=1}^{d}\left(x-e^{\frac{\pi i k}d}\right)=x^d-1$$
Now, write $n=dn'$ and $m=dm'$. Since
$$x^n-1=(x^d-1)\sum_{k=0}^{n'}x^k$$
$$x^m-1=(x^d-1)\sum_{k=0}^{m'}x^k$$
it follows that $x^d-1\mid \gcd(x^n-1,x^m-1)$ and we conclude:
$$\gcd(x^n-1,x^m-1)=x^d-1$$

Answer (score 2):

You can use induction on $\max\{m,n\}$. Let $m\ge n$.
If $m=1$ the requested is obvious. Let's assume that it is true for values $<m$. The requested is also obvious when $m=n$, so we can assume that $m>n$. Then $m=nq+r$
with $q,r\in\mathbb{Z_{>0}}$ and $0\leq r<n$. Then we know that gcd$(n,r)$=gcd$(m,n)=d$. Now we have: $$x^m-1=x^{nq+r}-1=x^rx^{nq}-x^r+x^r-1=x^r(x^{nq}-1)+x^r-1=x^rq(x)(x^n-1)+x^r-1.$$
So $\gcd(x^m-1,x^n-1)=\gcd(x^n-1,x^r-1)=x^{\gcd(n,r)}-1=x^d-1$.